# Configuring amq.topic binding with x-filter-jms-selector argument

Tags: qpid

Any idea how to configure amq.topic binding with x-filter-jms-selector argument?

I know how to do that in web admin UI.

[image]

If we are amending config file of qpid, then how to add this filter in that?

Answer (score 0):

Config json will have something like this -

```
{
"id" : "1c91c97b-df6d-44e8-bf5d-673e7f0133b5",
"name" : "amq.topic",
"type" : "topic",
"durableBindings" : [ {
  "arguments" : { },
  "bindingKey" : "*.*.event",
  "destination" : "test"
}, {
  "arguments" : {
    "x-filter-jms-selector" : "event NOT IN ('location', 'weather')"
  },
  "bindingKey" : "*.*.tick",
  "destination" : "test"
} ],
"lastUpdatedBy" : "guest",
"lastUpdatedTime" : 1590073211015,
"createdBy" : null,
"createdTime" : 1589575285215
}
```